Estoy iniciando programacion y da error para seleccionar de imagenes - Line 28: startDate.getValue(...).start is not a function, algun consejo
Estoy iniciando en programación y me arrojo este error para seleccionar fechas de analisis, que podra ser. estoy tratando de hacer un scrip que contemga varios indices espectrales para deteccion de vegetación ndvi, severidad de incendios, cuerpos de agua, detección de techos de casas rurale, con imagenes sentinel-2 en google earth engine.
// Botón de confirmación de selección de fechas
var confirmButton = ui.Button('Confirmar fechas', function() {
  var start = startDate.getValue().start();
  var end = endDate.getValue().end();
  


Saludos. Revisa la documentación de lo que estás usando a lo que hace referencias el startDate y endData; puede desde un simple error de mayúsculas y minúsculas o que realmente esa función no exista... sin una idea mejor de como tienes tu html, como inicializar/referencias de dichas variables es de momento lo que puedo sugerirte.

Así con lo que muestras es difícil, habría que ver de dónde vienen  startDate y endDate, pero al ojo me parece muy extraño el uso de funciones start() y end(), prueba quitarlas: var start = startDate.getValue() y lo mismo para el otro caso
